# Game freezes when too many pictures are loading in android

Tags: java, android, performance, sprite, game-engine

I have a game engine here and when I have to many pictures loading its freezing the game from time to time and not allowing it to run smoothly.  Now I am new to game programming so I think what is happening is I am loading the image over and over again causing the CPU to overload and slow down because it cant handle that many things at once.   I am creating a basic asteroid game, and when I shoot the missiles along with the asteroids coming at me its causing it to run slowly.  Is there a way to better structure this so I can only have the image load once, then reload that image everytime, rather than pulling it from the assets everytime a bullet is fired or an android image is loaded?

[Paste bin file, all of the needed code would be here.](http://pastebin.com/UfsLkP0i)

Comment: use profiler to detect problematic code. This is basic thing when you have problem with performance.

Comment: i dont see profiling in the perspective in eclipse. I am doing this for android?

Comment: Use Traceview in DDMS for profiling: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  a  game  you  cant  spend   more  33ms  (high performance games are in 16ms) drawing  and  updating  the game It  give  you  a minimun  of 30 fps (frames per secon).  it is well-know  that  in a  game to draw  spend  more time then update.   if  you are  drawing  a lot of sprites  and big surfaces, you frame rate  will be  bellow of  25 frames per second, and  you game will look  slow.

you can find  the nice  explanation here too. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVK6TKSx1lU

Comment: Thats exactly my issue, But i thought a game had to continuously update throughout the entire game play? But from what youre saying I have to go edit the updating part of the game

Comment: Which one engien  are  you using?, how many graphysc  you need draw?. Por example, this game http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOJ-EBnA1AM cannot get the minimun 22 FPS  with old devices of few resources. It  need draw many sprites for them.

Comment: I took care of the freezing by removing some things that are loading.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your game loop.  There are some great articles out there which might be of help - try this for starters: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/ but also as mentioned above, make sure everything is optimised to run as quickly as possible.